# Do I need to run the custom docker image in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-image

I've created a custom docker image as follows, and pushed it to a custom repo:

```
# Use php as parent image
FROM ruby:2.4-slim

# Install core prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5.6 python-pip python-dev build-essential zip software-properties-common wget

# Install awscli
RUN pip install awscli
```

Then I've added this custom image to my bitbucket-pipelines.yml like so:

```
image:
  name: xxx/adzooma-ruby:v1
  username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
  password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD

pipelines:
  tags:
    release-*:
      - step:
          script:
            - wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
...
```

My pipeline immediately fails when run due to:

```
+ wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
bash: wget: command not found
```

This sort of makes me think that actually my docker image isn't being used at all since I explicitly install **wget** in the image - so is my pipeline syntax correct or am I missing a step here?

Comment: what is the output of `docker run -it --rm xxx/adzooma-ruby:v1 which wget`? (some ideas: the push didn't work/you pushed a wrong image; $PATH is broken)

Answer (score 2):

You've have to define e-mail address too.

```
image:
  name: account-name/openjdk:8
  username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
  password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
  email: $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL
```

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-792298897.html

Comment: The docs seem to indicate that email is optional:
"You can also optionally include an email address, which may be required by some providers."
Unless by 'some providers' they mean Docker Hub!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced nearly the same issue with yours. The cause of my problem is, docker container registry somehow cannot capture the changes on my locally build docker image. To overcome the issue I've deleted images both on my local machine and my private docker container registry. Rebuild and Repush solved my problem. Maybe this can work for you too.

Comment: Ah thanks for that, I did notice that on the first build I could see it pulling the image, but on the subsequent one (where I'd added a couple of missing dependencies) it seemed to not do that, as if it were using a cached image.
Will try that tomorrow - thanks for the heads up.